# IsMouseOver trigger only returns true when the cursor is over the 'bottom' part of the button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style, ismouseover

I am fairly new to WPF, and I am trying to make a custom button where it changes to another specified colour when you hover over it. I have done this with partial success; the only problem is that only the bottom part of the button actually triggers the colour change.

Red **highlighted** area is the approximate hitbox. (not the long red strip, that's just decoration)

[image]

```xml
<!-- Button Markup-->
<Button Margin="4,0,4,0" >
    <Image Source="{StaticResource closeImg}"></Image>
</Button>

<!-- Button style -->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2B2B2B"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="28px"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28px"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Well.. If I will get your style and button from the code above everything seems to be fine on my solution. Can you provide more info? something about the image itself and the container for that button.

Comment: The image is a PNG located inside the resources folder of the application. It is defined in a parent grid's ResourceDictionary using the <BitMap> tag and it works fine. 

About the container, it's a bit too hard to explain in words. Instead, here's a PasteBin:
https://pastebin.com/g8SatAsz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that this was a slight quirk with the debug function with WPF and the WindowChrome class. This is fixed by adding the following to the style:

```xml
<Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"></Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

your solution seems to be good to me. I've tried the same thing on my vs and everything seems to be just fine. Perhaps there's something else connected with container that holds these buttons, or perhpas something with the image itself. Can you try to set the name for the border inside of a controlTemplate and set the TargetName inside of a trigger? Wonder if that could help

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2B2B2B"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="28px"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="28px"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: I get the error "The name "Bd" is not recognized" at TargetName="Bd". EDIT: Nevermind, I was just an idiot

Comment: Have you moved Trigger from Style. into ControlTemplate.Triggers?

Comment: I was just an idiot and didn't read your code carefully. Unfortunately, your fix didn't work.

Comment: hmm even when I have copy/pasted your code from the pastebin I'm not able to reproduce this behavior

Comment: images are transparent? This is the only thing that came to my mind. If these images have different background then transparent this would be it

Comment: All the images are are 256x256px and have transparent backgrounds. Here is a download for my images if it helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A96JkHI7WQnTsS-o2qXs5QMSqL-4mTM8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182872/discussion-between-cag2-and-pjrki).